# Rotation Tensor (Basic)

Tags: rotations

I got a question about rotation tensor: Refer to page 4 of [this file](https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?cid=5C08C07452173DEA&resid=5C08C07452173DEA%214735&app=WordPdf&wdo=1). There is an expression $$ n_{12} = \frac{1}{2\sin\phi_{12}} (R_{12} – R_{12}^T ).$$

I don’t know how it can be worked out….

In equation (3.11), trace of tensor is mentioned. Is $R_{ii}$ equal to sum of values in the diagonal?

Explanation in simple math is appreciated as I am not a maths student..

Comment: Can you fix your subject?

Comment: How can I change the subject?

Comment: Click "edit" and edit it. Right now, it is clearly incomplete.